# Media Browser doesn't show

Tags: 7, media

I've got the media module installed, but I'm not seeing the Media browser at all when I go to upload images.

[image]

Do I need to do something special to enable the media browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try checking the "media library" in the settings of the field, as seen on the picture in the [Quick Start Guide](http://drupal.org/node/1699054)

Comment: This did work, but that Quick Start Guide seems wildly out of date. Other than the Media Selector, everything after that doesn't show up for me. The admin/structure/file-types doesn't exist, etc. Weird.